# rosmsg show beginner_tutorials/Num can‘t work

Tags: rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the tutorial [Creating a ROS msg and srv](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv) ,in the 2.2 chapter, when I input the

```
rosmsg show beginner_tutorials/Num
```

I can't see:

```
int64 num
```

And when I input the

```
rosmsg show Num
```

I can't see

```
[beginner_tutorials/Num]:
int64 num
```

either.

What's the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/88086/rosmsg-show-beginner_tutorials/num-can%E2%80%98t-work/) by [hangzhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/7501/hangzhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2013-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know why your method doesn't work. But I finally figured out the problem. Before inputing:
$ rosmsg show Num. I should input these codes:
$ cd ~/catkin_ws/

$ catkin_make

$ source devel/setup.bash
Then the problem is solved. But I still don't know why.

---

Originally posted by [hangzhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/7501/hangzhang/) with karma: 88 on 2013-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 7